# Django get_queryset() trouble creating multiple annotation labels

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I am trying to get a few different annotation results to show in the Django Admin. I need these new results to be sortable columns as well. I came up with this (after reading EXTENSIVELY on SO):

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(BrandAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = Brand.objects.annotate(
        last_connection=Max('account__computer__last_connect')
    ).filter(
        account__computer__last_connect__gte=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=4))
    ).annotate(
        brand_count=Count('account__computer') 
    )            
    return qs   

def billable_computers(self, obj):
    return obj.brand_count   
billable_computers.admin_order_field = 'brand_count'

def last_connection(self, obj):
    return obj.last_connection                                                                           
last_connection.admin_order_field = 'last_connection'
```

This works, but returns with really weird (multiplied by some factor) results for the 'billable_computers'. I figured this was because of the chained annotations.

So I tried this:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(BrandAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = Brand.objects.filter(
        account__computer__last_connect__gte=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=4))
    ).all().distinct().annotate(
         brand_count=Count('account__computer') 
    )           
    qss = super(BrandAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qss = Brand.objects.annotate(
        last_connection=Max('account__computer__last_connect')
    )
    qs_all = qs | qss 
    return qs_all   

def billable_computers(self, obj):
    return obj.brand_count   
billable_computers.admin_order_field = 'brand_count'

def last_connection(self, obj):
    return obj.last_connection                                                                           
last_connection.admin_order_field = 'last_connection'
```

But this causes an error complaining that "'Brand' object has no attribute 'last_connection'".

So I tried this:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(BrandAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = Brand.objects.filter(
        account__computer__last_connect__gte=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=4))
    ).annotate(
        brand_count=Count('account__computer')
    )
    qs = Brand.objects.annotate(
         last_connection=Max('account__computer__last_connect')
    )
    return qs
```

But this give a "'Brand' object has no attribute 'brand_count'" error.

**About the models**: The Computer model has a foreign key to Account and Account has a foreign key to Brand. The Computer model has a datetime field labeled 'last_connect'. Every Brand can have unlimited Accounts and every Account can have unlimited Computers.

I just need to tally all the Computers (at each level) that have connected in the last 4 weeks. I also need a separate (sortable) column for the latest 'last_connect' value across all computers in the unfiltered set.

Obviously I am getting this wrong, but it seems like it should be so simple. I need two different metrics. I want to query them in the Admin and not at the model level. I don't want to make my models any more complicated than they are now.

Any advice is welcome! Thank you!